# Crystal Report Credentials Prompt after deployment

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, connection-string

I am Publishing crystal reports on remote server using the following code. when i try to run the crystal report page Crystal report viewer prompt me for database info. As the published crystal report were created using development server. In my crystal report i was using OLEDB ADO Connection

```
MyRepository _MyRepository = new MyRepository();            
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnStr"].ConnectionString;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand MyCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.spMySP");
MyCommand.Connection = myConnection;
MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@PositionID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (cmbPositions.SelectedValue == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(cmbPositions.SelectedValue));
MyCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter MyDA = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
MyDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
ASale _DS = new ASale();
MyDA.Fill(_DS, "dbo.spMySP");
rptSale oRpt = new rptSale();
oRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "mypass");
oRpt.SetDataSource(_DS);
oRpt.SetParameterValue(0, "param1");
oRpt.SetParameterValue(1, "param2");
oRpt.SetParameterValue(2, "param3" );
oRpt.SetParameterValue(3, (cmbPositions.SelectedValue == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(cmbPositions.SelectedValue)));
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt;
```

Comment: I need to change setDatabaseLogon so that it can also access credentials from web.config

Answer (score 0):

HI,

When you develop your report, do you use Windows authentication to login to the database to build the report?

Maybe you can try to open the report again and try to update your database set up on the crystal report. E.g. by using the same login information your use on your code.

What I normally do is to put the database server name and the database name on to the code as well
E.G.
_CReportDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(username, pw, ServerName, DB)

Not sure if it could help

Comment: But i want to set this information through web.config so that i don't need to change my reports' code for publishing

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes you set this information through web.config. e.g. in the AppSettings section E.g. the username, password, servername and database name of the report. then you can use
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Servername"] to retrieve the information and put it into the SetDatabaseLogon method. I guess you do need to publish this one more time.